# VisualPHPUnit 2.2 gives me BAD JSON

Tags: php, json, phpunit

I'm using VisualPHPUnit 2.2 and PHPUnit 4.3.1 (installed with phar) and selenium and if I run it in command line it works and if I run it from VisualPHPUnit it runs, but the JSON is not exported properly.
Hier is what I see as exported JSON in inspector:

```
{  
   "event":"test",
   "suite":"WebTest",
   "test":"WebTest::testTitle",
   "status":"pass",
   "time":2.4046840667725,
   "trace":[  

   ],
   "message":"",
   "output":""
}{  
   "suites":[  

   ],
   "stats":{  
      "suites":{  
         "succeeded":0,
         "skipped":0,
         "incomplete":0,
         "failed":0,
         "total":0,
         "percentSucceeded":0,
         "percentSkipped":0,
         "percentIncomplete":0,
         "percentFailed":0
      },
      "tests":{  
         "succeeded":0,
         "skipped":0,
         "incomplete":0,
         "failed":0,
         "total":0,
         "percentSucceeded":0,
         "percentSkipped":0,
         "percentIncomplete":0,
         "percentFailed":0
      }
   },
   "errors":[  

   ],
   "notifications":[  

   ]
}
```

The problem with this is: Multiple JSON root elements

So somewhere the php export don't work as it should be, or it is some other issue?

Other thing if I turn all errors with next code:

```
      error_reporting(E_ALL);
      ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

I get some warnings between JSON:

```
{ "event": "test", "suite": "WebTest", "test": "WebTest::testTitle", "status": "pass", "time": 2.4141600131989, "trace": [ ], "message": "", "output": ""}Notice: ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete in /var/www/app/lib/VPU.php on line 441
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/interweb/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:172) in /var/www/nx/core/Response.php on line 145

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/interweb/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:172) in /var/www/nx/core/Response.php on line 147
{"suites":[],"stats":{"suites":{"succeeded":0,"skipped":0,"incomplete":0,"failed":0,"total":0,"percentSucceeded":0,"percentSkipped":0,"percentIncomplete":0,"percentFailed":0},"tests":{"succeeded":0,"skipped":0,"incomplete":0,"failed":0,"total":0,"percentSucceeded":0,"percentSkipped":0,"percentIncomplete":0,"percentFailed":0}},"errors":[],"notifications":[]}
```

Hier is my config/bootstrap.php

```
// The directory where PEAR is located
'pear_path'      => '/usr/share/php',

// The directories where the tests reside
'test_directories' => array(
    "/home/websites/root/application/classes/controller/admin/unit/test/classes/"
),
```

...

```
require_once '/home/inter/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '/home/inter/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Log/JSON.php';
```

So anyone can help me with this, on other server it works fine, but with some older PHPUnit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i tried it too, and spent a full day on solving the issue.
The solution is very simple though:

In VPU.php find the function run_tests

change the line

```
$result->addListener(new \PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON();
```

to

```
$result->addListener(new \PHPUnit_Util_Log_JSON("/tmp/res.json")); // or any other file you want to output to.
```

then comment the line

```
$results = ob_get_contents();
```

and change it to:

```
    $results = file_get_contents("/tmp/res.json"); // or the file you set as output file in Listener
```

Also you should change in the same file all the lines with:

```
ob_end_clean();
```

to

```
if (ob_get_length()) ob_end_clean();
```

That worked for me.

Comment: looks like VPU is not developed further, so your answer is the best i could find to make it work. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @yuriscom for going the first steps. But with the workaround above XML files still fail. So I dug a bit further into VPU and PHPUnit 4.2+. What I found is a CONST "PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE" need to be set for PHPUnit 4.2+ to work correctly regarding output buffering (see line 1882 in PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase, version 4.6).

So now the only thing you need to do is to set that CONST instead of all the changes mentioned above. I did it in the newly added constructor for the VPU class (file "VisualPHPUnit\2.2\app\lib\VPU.php" right at the top) like this:

```
class VPU {

    // added this function, not showing original annotations above
    public function __construct()
    {
        define('PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE', true);
    }

    ... // rest of class
}
```

Now VPU works with single tests selectet from the menue and with XML files. Hope this helps (and is true for) everyone having the same problem.